# Create a bar plot with 2 columns of a data frame in the x-axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a 2 columns of a data frame say

```
t1=data.frame(c1=c("Y","N","U","Y","N","U"),c2=c("Y","N","N","U","U","Y"))
```

I want to create a bar plot with both columns on the x axis and the number of occurrences of Y,N and U as 3 separate bars for each of the columns.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option to achieve this with `tidyverse`:

#### Edit: This is probably what you wanted:

```
library(tidyverse)
t1 %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "name", values_to = "Let") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name, fill=Let))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge")
```

[image]

#### Previous post

```
library(tidyverse)
t1 %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "name", values_to = "Let") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Let, fill=name))+
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But i was looking for a plot where C1 and C2 are on the x axis and 3 bars(Frequency of Y,N and U) for each column C1 and C2

Comment: I modified the code above, see edit